# Is it wrong to conduct a non parametric statistical test when the p values are greater than 0.05?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, research-design

If the obtained statistical data in a research were tested using Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test and the test was rejected or in other words data were normally distributed, is it possible to utilize the non parametric statistical tests such as Mann–Whitney U or Wilcoxon singed‑rank tests? if not what parametric tests would you recommend to use in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What questions do you have about your data? That is, why analyze the data at all?

Comment: @Dave, I have 5 samples and these samples are compared in different types of forms such as minimum, mean and standard deviation and another type of information about the data. When conducting the KS test, I realized that the p values for min, mean and standard deviation are greater than 0.05 which rejects the possibility of doing  non-parametric tests. However for the last type of data i obtain the values for samples less than 0.05 which can be an indication of the possibility of utilizing a non-parametric test on the data. What i am looking for is that can i still use non-parametric tests?

Comment: What are you testing with the KS test and why?

Comment: @Dave, I am comparing a novel method with some existing ones. The purpose is to find out the superiority of the data obtained by my method over the existing methods.

Comment: But how does KS factor into that? All KS does is test if two distributions are the same.

Comment: @Dave, Yes you are right. I am trying to find out which kind of tests should  i use. Parametric tests or non-parametric tests. The aim of using KS test is to determine which one to choose.

Comment: But how does KS tell you that? Do you test for normality and go for Wilcoxon if normality is rejected and a t-test otherwise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146822/discussion-between-dave-and-sherl-lol).